# How to create OrientGraph from embedded OrientServer?

Tags: orientdb

I understand that it is possible to create a embedded OrientDB¹ server using:

```
OServer server = OServerMain.create();
```

What i don't understand is how to create or open a OrientGraph using the OrientGraphFactory. What is needed to connect both systems. (OServer, OrientGraph)?

I normally create my OrientGraph this way:

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:" + options.getDirectory()).setupPool(5, 100);
OrientGraphNoTx noTx = factory.getNoTx();
```

I don't want to connect to my graph using "remote:" if possible since this would potentially create network layer within my embedded server.

My actual goals are:

- Open the graph using the OrientDB workbench for inspection
- Enable OrientDB Graph database distribution.

[1] http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Embedded-Server.html

Comment: if you open it with plocal: you will bypass the network layer.
And you can launch the OServerMain to be able to connect to the database with remote: or studio if you want

Comment: OServer will automatically detect databases i opened using OrientGraphFactory?

Comment: if you configure ORIENTDB_HOME, then the server will look for databases in $ORIENTDB_HOME/databases. Otherwise you can create the server with a custom orientdb-server-config.xml. See here
http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/DB-Server.html#storages

Comment: I believe i tried this approach but somehow i could not connect to the graph since some graph user credentials were missing. Do i need to set those permissions when i create the graph using OrientGraphFactory?

Comment: It seems that admin/admin is the default login for databases that were created using OrientGraphFactory